# Javascript: How to get length of a line in canvas by inch (or milimeter)

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, html5-canvas

In javascript, we can draw a line in canvas with the length is in pixel.
For example:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(300,0);
ctx.stroke();
```

If I want to convert the length of the line to inch or milimeter, is there any way to do that?

Comment: So I project it onto a screen on the wall, one inch on my screen is now 3 feet.... Not sure how you would expect to get accurate measurements.

Comment: @epascarello thats true :D but i think it is possible to evaluate the mm on a display because every information needed should be available

Comment: You need to know the DPI of the screen/projector. https://uproer.com/articles/image-size-calculator-px-in/

Comment: for a resolution of 96dpi 1px = 0.264583333mm. In your case your line has a length of 300px. So 300 * 0.264583333 = 79.375mm